# Uncover unique symbols

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, computational-mathematics

Lets say I have a 6 letter word.

I send the 6 letters in two different ways. The first time I send it in the original order and the second time I send it in the following order: 4 5 6 1 2 3. There is exactly one removal in each observed set. For how many removals can I not correctly unscramble the message?

I did hand computation by checking each combination. I received 6/36 messages as not recoverable: (1,4) (2,5), (3,6), (4,1), (5,2), (6,3). Have I converged on the right calculations?

Comment: The first part seems correct to me. I think you should mention your assumption that the receiver knows that the message is 6 letters long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations are not correct.  $(1,1)$ should not be decodable in the first case and $(1,2)$ should not be decodable in the second.  These are just examples.  You should still find that there are more cases you cannot decode in the first case because changing the order will mean more cases can be decoded because there are fewer pairs that are next to each other in both transmissions.

Comment: Sorry, there might be a misunderstanding. But I said (1,1) is not decodable in the first case.

Comment: Yes, I thought the first parenthesis was explaining what followed.  In the second case if you delete a pair that is supposed to be together in both transmissions you can't decode it just like the first, but you remove the $(3,4)$ and $(4,3)$ cases.  The point of the exercise is to show the gain from scrambling.

Comment: I removed the (3,4) and (4,3) cases because in the 2nd case, the first position is a 3, but the 4th position is a 1. So it can actually be decoded can't it?

Comment: Yes, but $(5,6), (6,5)$ et al should still be there.

Comment: (5,6), (6,5) are there in the list of undecodable combinations in the first experiment. But in the 2nd experiment, they are decodable.

Comment: I don't think so.  In the case of $(5,6)$ the first is received as $12346$ and the second as $45123$, but it could have been $12345$ and $46123$ so you can't decode it.  The logic is the same as the first case when the two numbers are next to each other in both transmissions.

Comment: Hmm, I think the notation that I have used might have been misleading. When I say (5,6), it actually means 5th position in the first set and the 6th position in the second set. Not the 6th bit. But I see that my answer does not even reflect my own convention. Very sorry about that. Let me fix this.

Comment: Yes, but then $(5,3)$ is not decodable in the second case.

Comment: You are right. So that means, there is no gain from scrambling then? Because as you pointed out, (5,3), (6, 2), etc... But shouldn't interleaving actually aid the process of decoding? Also, can you please update your answer to reflect the correct answer or should I fix my own post so that future viewers can see what is the correct answer?

Comment: There is some gain, as $(3,4)$ in the first would become $(3,1)$ in the second and you can decode it now.  That is the only pair that is broken up, so the gain is rather small.  If you had a long message you could do more scrambling and break up more pairs for more gain.

Comment: You will see this in much more general contexts.  There is a general principle that you would like every data bit to influence a lot of the transmitted bits to improve error detection.  If each data bit only changes a few transmitted bits, it is often easy to come up with errors that cancel out the effects on the check bits, but if things are spread widely that is much harder.  Similarly for encryption-you want each change in a bit of the key to be spread throughout the message.  Entropy is important.